# login on server doesn't work, locally it does

Tags: php, mysql, apache, wamp

My login on the server (apache) does not work, but I do get it to work locally (WAMP). I have tried using the database of the server with my WAMP and that worked as well, but as soon as the files or on the server it stops working. I've checked all the links and they are correct. The server doesn't give any error message, it just keeps on going back to the same page (not_logged_in.php).

The code I use is as follows:

index.php

```
<?php
require_once('../includes/additions/initialize.php');
require_once(FUNCTIONS);
require_once(SESSION);  

// ... ask if we are logged in here:
if (logged_in()) {
    // the user is logged in
   include(ADDITIONS."logged_in.php");

} else {
    // the user is not logged in
   include(ADDITIONS."not_logged_in.php");
}
?>
```

Where the logged_in() function is as follows:

```
function logged_in() {
    // confirm logged in
    return isset($_SESSION['restaurant_user_id']); // restaurants
}
```

It then goes to not_logged_in.php, which has this code:

```
<?php require_once(VALIDATION);?>
<?php require_once(HEADER);?>

<?php

$user_name = "";

if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    // process the form

    $required_fields = array('user_name', "password" );
    validate_presences($required_fields);

    if (empty($errors)) {
        // attemt login
        $user_name = mysql_prep($_POST["user_name"]);
        $password = mysql_prep($_POST["password"]);

        $found_user = attempt_login_restaurant($user_name, $password);


            if ($found_user) {
            // Success 
            // Mark user as logged in
            $_SESSION["restaurant_user_id"] = $found_user["restaurant_user_id"];
            $_SESSION["email_address"] = $found_user["email_address"];
            $_SESSION["user_name"] = $found_user["user_name"];

            $_SESSION["message"] = "Welcome ". htmlentities($_SESSION["user_name"]) . ", you are now logged in";

            redirect_to(WEBSITE_ROOT. "index.php");

        } else {
            $_SESSION["message"] = "E-mail/password not found.";

}   }       }else {}

echo message();
echo form_errors($errors);
?>
<div id="mainContent" class="fluid">
<div class="restaurantphoto">
<div class="width">

<section class="login">
<form method="post" action="<?php echo WEBSITE_ROOT; ?>index.php">
    <label for="user_name"><?php echo WORDING_USERNAME; ?></label><br />
    <input id="user_name" type="text" name="user_name" value="<?php echo  htmlentities($user_name); ?>" required /><br />
    <label for="user_password"><?php echo WORDING_PASSWORD; ?></label><br />
    <input id="user_password" type="password" name="password" autocomplete="off" required />
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="<?php echo WORDING_LOGIN; ?>" />
    <br /><br />
</form>
<br />
<a href="<?php echo ADDONS; ?>password_reset.php"><?php echo     WORDING_FORGOT_MY_PASSWORD; ?></a> 
</section>
</section>
</div>
</div>

<?php include(FOOTER); ?>
```

The functions which are being used here are:

```
function has_presence($value) {
// check if it is not empty
return isset($value) && $value !== "";
}

function validate_presences($required_fields) {
global $errors;
foreach ($required_fields as $field) {
    $value = trim($_POST[$field]);
    if (!has_presence($value)) {
            $errors[$field] = fieldname_as_text($field) . " can't be blank";
        }   }
}
function find_restaurant_by_email($email) {
global $db;

$safe_email = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $email);

$query = "SELECT * ";
$query .= "FROM database_restaurants ";
$query .= "WHERE email_address = '{$safe_email}' ";
$query .= "LIMIT 1";
$user_set = mysqli_query($db, $query);
// test if there is a query error
confirm_query($user_set);
if ($user = mysqli_fetch_assoc($user_set)) {
return $user;
} else {
    return null;
}
}

function find_restaurant_by_user_name($user_name) {
global $db;

$safe_user_name = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $user_name);

$query = "SELECT * ";
$query .= "FROM database_restaurants ";
$query .= "WHERE user_name = '{$safe_user_name}' ";
$query .= "LIMIT 1";
$user_set = mysqli_query($db, $query);
// test if there is a query error
confirm_query($user_set);
if ($user = mysqli_fetch_assoc($user_set)) {
return $user;
} else {
    return null;
}
}

function attempt_login_restaurant($login_info, $password) {
// restaurants
$user = find_restaurant_by_email($login_info);
if (!$user) {   
    $user = find_restaurant_by_user_name($login_info);
}
if ($user) {
    // found user, now check password
    if (password_check($password, $user["password"])) {
        // password matches
        return $user;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
} else {
    // admin not found
    return false;
}
}

function password_check($password, $existing_hash) {
// existing hash contains format and salt at start
$hash = crypt($password, $existing_hash);
if ($hash === $existing_hash) {
    return true;    
} else {
    return false;
}
}
```

As it also doesn't reflect a message on the website, I think that there is something going wrong before the if (empty($errors)) statement or that there is something going wrong with the session (yes I did start the session, it's in the session.php file). The strange part is that everything is working just fine locally. I hope you guys can help, this is really breaking my head!!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I would echo all session variables out then exit to see what get's stored.

Comment: @Demodave Just do `var_dump($_SESSION);` in that case, much easier.

Comment: Also, I would check if apache's session_module is enabled. https://httpd.apache.org/docs/trunk/mod/mod_session.html

Comment: @Demodave It just returns an empty array, before ad after I try to login

Comment: @Demodave The session_module should be enabled, other session related things on the server work